# How to debug mongoerror?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, axios, nuxt.js

This is probably a straightforward question. If so, please excuse me.

I'm doing axios requests to nuxt, which does mongoose requests. For example, I have this function here:

```
  let aggregation = [
    {$unwind: {path:"$versions"}}, 
    {$match: {}},
    {$group: {
      _id:    "$_id",
      versions: {$push: 
        {nlp : "$versions.nlp"}
      }
    } }
  ]
  scraps = await Scraps.aggregate(aggregation);
```

However, I keep having this sort of errors:

```
{"ok":0,"code":16945,"codeName":"Location16945","name":"MongoError"}
Request failed with status code 500

  at createError (node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:236:11)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I don't know what is causing this bug, as the error is not explicit to me.

My question: beyond this very specific example, do you have an idea, a method, or a tool, to provide a comprehensive explanation and/or to debug such errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Your match stage is empty

Comment: I have another similar request with empty match and it works. Also, it bugs the same way without the stage. Most importantly, I'm not looking at debugging this specific bug, but rather have a general method. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on `code`. Error codes do not often change due to backward compatibility. Some may be added. In that case, you need to refer `error.md` file from the source code of the specific version.

[list of codes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/35079a95ebc591dee47ecca5e0f22eb7a7381fd0/docs/errors.md)

> 16945 code Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. `Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in`.

Highlighted portion is one of the possible solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know this page.

Comment: Glad, it helped. happy coding

Comment: Actually, I now have a code "40234" which is not listed on your page. Any idea?

Comment: The error codes which I am shared for version 3. It looks like error is related to 3.6+. We need to check at error.md of 3.6's source code

Comment: I see. However, I'm unable to find a similar doc for new versions (e.g., 4.4). Only this (incomplete) page: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/base/error_codes.yml Any idea? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I will chekc that and post your query in another question. Someone may help you to fix the query without codes.

Comment: This list seems no longer to be maintained.